# SnackBar en flutter recibe Null

Tags: flutter

Me larga el siguiente error al presionar el boton login:

I/flutter (19258): The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.
I/flutter (19258): Receiver: null
I/flutter (19258): Tried calling: showSnackBar(Instance of 'SnackBar')

Copio el codigo de la clase donde uso el SnackBar:

```
    class login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _loginState createState() => _loginState();

}

class _loginState extends State<login> {
  String usuario,contrasena;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  _showSnackBar() {
    final snackBar = new SnackBar(
        content: new Text('asdasd'),
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 5),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      /*action: new SnackBarAction(label: 'Ok', onPressed: (){

      }),*/
    );

    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Login'),),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),

          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      icon:  new Icon(Icons.verified_user),
                      hintText: 'Escriba aqui su usuario por favor',
                      labelText: 'Cual es su usuario?'
                  ),

                  onChanged: (String e) {
                    setState((){
                    usuario = e;
                    });
                  }
                ),
                new TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    icon:  Icon (Icons.arrow_forward),
                    hintText: 'Escriba aqui su contrasena por favor',
                    labelText: 'Recuerda su contrasena?'
                  ),

                    onChanged: (String e) {
                      setState((){
                        contrasena = e;
                      });
                    }

                ),
                new InkWell(
                    child: Container (
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 25.0,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3.0)),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,

                          ),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      height: 40.0,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('Entrar'),
                      ),
                    ),


                    onTap:() {
                    if (usuario.toString().trim() != '' && contrasena.toString().trim() != '' ){    //chequea con contenga texto en usuario y contrasena
                      fetchPost(usuario, contrasena);  //fetchPost se encuentra en la clase usuario.dart conecta con la base de datos
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => menu()),

                      );
                    }else{
                      _showSnackBar();
                    }


                    }
                    )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )

    );

  }

}
```

copie y pegue las partes de la clase que se usa el snack porque no me deja copiar el codigo completo por politicas de stack.
no encuentro el error, es por que es una clase StateFull ?
O eso no influye ? 
Como puedo solucinarlo?
desde ya muchas gracias..

Comment: asignaste correctamente el _scaffoldKey ?  no veo esa parte. Puedes agregar tu código a gist.github.com  y pegar el link

Comment: @diegoveloper no hice más de lo que está en el código... Que me faltaría?

Comment: Pon el código del build method, para ver el Scaffold

Comment: @diegoveloper ahi edite la publi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas declarando `GlobalKey` pero no se lo asignas al `Scaffold` por lo tanto el State es null, necesitas asignarlo de esta forma:

```
 return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Login'),),
         ...
```